# if $L \notin RE$ and $L' \notin RE$ then $L \cup L' \notin RE$

Tags: computer-science, computability

Question: **if** $L \notin RE$ **and** $L' \notin RE$ **then** $L \cup L' \notin RE$

I need to prove or give a counter-example.

First of all, I want to understand if I'm correct:

(1) **If** $L \notin RE$, can I conclude that $L \in co-RE$? Because from my understanding if $L \notin RE$, it means for me that for every input $x$ that is **not** in $L$ the machine says **no**. Otherwise, it **doesn't** say no. Which is exactly like on $co-RE$.

If I'm wrong up there,

(2) can I conclude that **if** $L \notin RE$ **then** $L^{c} \in RE$ ?

Here is ' my proof' **if** $L \notin RE$ **then** $L^c \notin co-RE$ which is $L^c \in (co-RE)^c$ which is $L^c \in RE$

If yes on (2), then I need to prove that **if** $L^c \in RE$ **and** $L'^c \in RE$ **then** $(L \cup L')^c \in RE$ which is $ L^c \cap L'^c \in RE $ - which is true because they've closure in $\cap$.

Now, if I'm correct at (1) or at (2) then we know that there's closure for Union for languages that are in $RE$ or in $co-RE$, so it's true by their definition.

Would love to know if I'm correct on (1) or on (2).

Here's a list of questions I'm struggling with, thus I can't answer the question efficiently:

1. if $L \notin RE$ can I conclude $L \in co-RE$?
2. What's the definition of $L \notin RE$?
3. if $L \notin RE$ then $L^c \notin co-RE$?
4. if $L \notin RE$ then $L^c \notin RE$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ denote the halt set in a reasonable form. Similarly let's denote $L'=\mathbb{N}-L$. Also, you can search for "join" on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree.

**Question:** if $L_1 \notin RE$ and $L_2 \notin RE$ then $L_1 \cup L_2 \notin RE$

This is incorrect. In particular, take $L_1=H \oplus H'$ and $L_2=H' \oplus H$. Neither $L_1$ or $L_2$ are r.e. However, we have $L_1 \cup L_2 =\mathbb{N}$. Of course we have $\mathbb{N} \in RE$.

**(1)** $L \notin RE$ implies $L \in coRE$

This is incorrect. Define $X=RE \cup coRE$. Now if you take any set $L$ such that $L \notin X$, then clearly $L \notin RE$. However, $L \notin coRE$ would also be true for obvious reasons.

**(2)** $L \notin RE$ implies $L' \in RE$

This is also incorrect. One way is to define $L=H \oplus H'$. Then $L \notin RE$. But we then have $L'=H' \oplus H$ (and $L' \notin RE$ either).

A second way is to define a set $L$ such that $H \leq_T L$ but $L \nleq_T H$. In that case also $L \notin RE$ (since $L \in RE$ that would imply $L \leq_T H$). But we also have $L' \notin RE$. That's true because if by contradiction we assume $L' \in RE$ then we have $L \in coRE$. However, $L \in coRE$ that would imply $L \leq_T H$.

Comment: What is $H$, $H'$, and the sign between them? Thanks for ur answer.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS By $H'$ I simply mean the complement of $H$ (w.r.t. $\mathbb{N}$). That is $H'=\mathbb{N}-H$. As far as I know, this notation is used fairly widely (though it does conflict with the notation you used in your question .... and that might have caused some confusion). In the notation of your question, $L'$ and $H'$ could be denoted as $L^c$ and $H^c$ respectively.

Comment: Also, one other useful fact is that "$L \in RE$ if and only $L' \in coRE$".

Comment: Thanks. What's is "the halt set in a reasonable form"?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS You would probably be aware of the halt function $h:\mathbb{N^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. $h(a,b)$ means that when a program with index $a$ halts on input $b$ it returns $1$ (and $0$ otherwise). Now $h$ is not a computable function (cont.)

Comment: One could use a set $H$ where $H=\{ <a,b> | \,$ program with index $a$ halts on input $b$ $\, \}$. Here $<a,b>$ is a computable bijective function from $\mathbb{N^2}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $L$ is a set of natural numbers, $L'$ is the Turing jump of $L$, also a set of natural numbers, and $L^c$ is its complement. Then if $L$ and $L'$ are both non-RE, $L \cup L'$ can be RE, but typically is not.

Hint for an example of yes: Try defining an infinite set $A$ such that $A$ is contained in $M'$ for every language $M$. Then as long as $L^c$ is contained in $A$, you always have $L \cup L' = \mathbb{N}$, which is RE.

Hint for example of no: Try to get an infinite computable set $B$ that is contained in $M^{\prime c}$ for every language $M$. Then as long as $L$ is contained in $B$, the union $L \cup L'$ is one-one equivalent to the join $L \oplus L'$, and in particular is RE only if $L$ is RE.

Comment: I guess $\bar{L}$ might be better than $L'$ for denoting complement (in case of potential ambiguity). Let's denote $L'$ to mean the jump of $L$ for this comment. I looked up the "formal" definition of jump, but I am not quite certain what you mean by: "if $L$ and $L'$ are RE, $L \cup L'$ can be RE, but typically is not." Let $L$ be any recursive set. Then $L'$ must be r.e. for quite simple reason .... we can easily explicitly enumerate the elements of $L'$.  So $L \cup L'$ is also r.e. (because both $L$ and $L'$ are).

Comment: Once, crucially, in this answer I wrote 'RE' when I meant 'not RE'. I am going to edit this serious errors out.